# Add database connection DB2/400 (iSerie / IBM i)

Tags: geoserver, java, db2, jdbc

We are finding it difficult to connect to the **DB2/400** database, it is the same **DB2 for IBM i**. Usually we use a Java package called **jt400.jar** that encompasses the JDBC driver to DB2 for IBM i.

The extension provided by Geoserver to connect to the DB2 store does not work with ours, as it belongs to **DB2 to z/OS**!

Is there any form of the **jt400.jar** package. Give it be reconnected as an extension to the Geoserver store?

In the **jt400.jar** package we use the class:

**DRIVERNAME** = com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver

**URL** = jdbc:as400://host:NAME_DATABASE;date format=iso;time format=iso;prompt=false;user=USER;password=PASSWORD;

Note: It is not necessary to inform the port

Comment: What does not work? You can try adding your preferred jar and see what happens, but you could well be on your own as I don't know of anyone who uses the DB2 connection plugin and I don't know if it's actively developed

Comment: There is no extension for Geoserver that connects to the "DB2 for IBM i" database!

Comment: The DB2 for Geoserver extension is only available to connect to IBM's "DB2 for z/OS" database.

Comment: Here in my company we have the DB2/400 database that runs on the IBM i operating system.

Comment: Maybe you can develop one based on the existing code base

Comment: Thanks!

I'll try to develop, but I don't have much knowledge of how Geoserver works.